# /bin/sh orphaned link - have I been hacked?

Tags: linux, bash

Just today I found that when I log in to my linux server, I receive an error message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This seems to be because my `/bin/sh` is an orphaned link. It points to `z` which doesn't exist.

Also under `/bin` is `rzsh -> /etc/alternatives/rzsh` and `tmp -> /etc/alternatives/zsh` which also don't exist.

I'm hoping any issues I'm having will be fixed simply by relinking /bin/sh to dash. But I'm feeling uncertain about all this. I have no idea how this could have come to be.

Is it possible this is the result of a halfway-successful automated attack? Everything else in my server seems relatively intact.

What else could have caused this problem? It was working fine yesterday.

Comment: Be it by an external attack, a local buggy application, a misconfiguration or a hardware problem, your system is no longer in a stable state. IMHO you should save all your data (if you do not have recent backups) and re-install.

Comment: Yes I was planning on doing that. It's about time I rebuilt this server anyway.